# Why is the python import behavior different when I run a program using the interpreter versus when I import it as a module?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Suppose I have the following directory structure,

```
root
└───test
        a.py
        b.py
```

The file `a.py` contains the following:

```
import b
```

The file `b.py` contains the following:

```
print("b is imported")
```

If my current directory is `root`, and I run `python test/a.py` I get the following output:

```
b is imported
```

This is confusing to me, because if I start an interpreter, I cannot import `b`:

```
$ python
Python 3.10.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Dec 22 2021, 01:33:54) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
```

How is it, then, that given the same current working directory, `a` knows about `b` when I run it as a program, but not when I try to import it as a module?

Comment: ``python test/a.py`` tells Python about the ``test`` directory. A bare ``python`` doesn't.

Comment: Working directories aren't relevant to the search path when running a script; the directory containing the main script is. See the documentation for [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Comment: https://realpython.com/lessons/module-search-path/